# How to import DSA signature in ASN.1 format using BouncyCastle (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, asn.1

OpenSSL, as well as most other DSA implementations, outputs signatures in ASN.1 format. Thus, the 40-byte signature (two 20-byte integers) becomes 46 bytes due to the ASN.1 structure headers. (See [this forum post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=144622) for details.)

My question is, **how does one handle this format in C#?** (or elsewhere, for that matter)

I spent a while trying to deal with it using the .NET `System.Security.Crypto` packages, but gave up on that (*really frustrating, because it clearly has internal code to parse ASN.1 since it can read DER format, but there's no way for you to use it -- but I digress...*)

Then, I started working with the BouncyCastle C# library. I can get it into an `Asn1Object`, and if I expand it while debugging I see that it contains a `DerSequence` with the two integers, but how do I pull them out (preferably into `BigIntegers` so I can feed them to `DSA.VerifySignature`?)

Code sample:

```
Byte[] msgText = ReadFile("test_msg.txt");
Byte[] msgSigRaw = ReadFile("test_sig_1.bin");  // reads binary ASN.1 sig using FileStream
Asn1Object sigASN = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(msgSigRaw);  // parses into Asn1Object
...
X509Certificate implCert = ReadCertificate("pubcert_dsa.cer");  // cert in DER format
DsaSigner DSA = new DsaSigner();
DSA.Init(false, implCert.GetPublicKey());
...
BigInteger sigIntR, sigIntS;
... //TODO: how to get signature from sigASN into sigIntR, sigIntS?
Boolean validSig = DSA.VerifySignature(msgText, sigIntR, sigIntS);  // my goal
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/CryptoInteropSign.aspx

It contains code to convert the DSA signature into the P1363 format expected in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Some example code of how to verify a DSA signature in BouncyCastle C#:

```
ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withDSA");
sig.Init(false, implCert.GetPublicKey());
sig.BlockUpdate(msgText, 0, msgText.Length);
bool valid = sig.VerifySignature(msgSigRaw);
```

Note that this signer will deal with the ASN.1 and the calculation of the message digest (I've assumed SHA-1 was used here) for you.

If you still really want to know how the conversions of the {r,s} values to/from ASN.1 happen, then have a look in the source for DsaDigestSigner. Internally it does the appropriate ASN.1 encoding/decoding and then uses DsaSigner class for the low-level sig operation.